# Install interruption

Tags: installation, 13.10

I have a partitioned machine Vista/13.04. When installing 13.10 upgrade, I had a power outage. Now I can't start the machine in Ubuntu. I'm not sure what to do next. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Me in your situation would do a clean installation:

- boot with a USB drive to a live session
- do a backup of your documents
- install Ubuntu again formatting the root "/" partition

Your boot loader should be reinstalled and everything back to normal with Ubuntu 13.10 in place :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try to upgrade via the command line, try the instructions [here](http://lawrit.lawr.ucdavis.edu/it-help-center/how-to/upgrading-ubuntu-via-command-line)

In a nutshell, run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: The OP says that he cannot boot Ubuntu, so he cannot do this.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.